# Control which aestheic to use in ggplot2 function

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I want to make a series of examples and trying to use a function. How do I control whether shape, alpha, size, etc. are used? Here is the code I am using:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot_example <- 
  function(aesthetic, var){  
    ggplot(mpg) +
    geom_point(aes(x = displ, y = hwy, 
                   aesthetic = get(var)))
  }

ggplot_example("color", "hwy")
ggplot_example("color", "class")
ggplot_example("alpha", "cty")
ggplot_example("size", "cty")
```

Right now `get(aesthetic) = get(var)` is throwing an error and when I just use `aesthetic = get(var)` it ignores the `aesthetic` argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably read up on [metaprogramming in Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/). You can't just stick variables anywhere. You need to be careful to recognize whether the function requires a string, a symbol, or an expression and need to be able to make one from the other.

The easiest way to do make your function work is probably with `do.call()` to dynamically build the `aes()` call while using `setNames()` to set parameter names. Try this

```
ggplot_example <- 
  function(aesthetic, var){  
    ggplot(mpg) +
    geom_point(do.call("aes", setNames(list(quote(displ), quote(hwy), 
                   as.name(var)), c("x", "y", aesthetic))))
  }

ggplot_example("color", "hwy")
ggplot_example("color", "class")
ggplot_example("alpha", "cty")
ggplot_example("size", "cty")
```

Comment: Oh wow, I have much to learn. I was no where close when looking for it. Thank you.